# Forms Authentication enabled IIS 8.5 website is not storing my identity

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017, forms-authentication, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a legacy ASP.Net application that is using Form Authentication. The project is using .NET 4 framework and is running on a Windows Server 2012R2 and IIS 8.5. I am developing in Visual Studio 2017 and the legacy code is in VB.Net.

I have a Production version of the server that has been running for a while and is working OK. However, I am trying to create a Development version and a Production Version to run on two separate servers.

The new version I am trying to set up for the Development server is having the following problem;

I can log in OK and get authenticated against the backing database. I am using InProc Sessions and I put the info in a session object that gets checked by protected pages using the Forms Authentication process. However, in the development version, I keep getting thrown back to the login page like it is not retaining the session data but I can't determine why this is happening.

When I log in again I go to the intended page but every time I switch to another protected page, I have to log in again.

Below is the web.config for the development server.

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>

    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MAILnet.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>

    <sectionGroup name="devExpress">
      <section name="themes" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ThemesConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="compression" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.CompressionConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="settings" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.SettingsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
      <section name="errors" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ErrorsConfigurationSection, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>

    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <!-- NOTE: Connection strings are set in the appSettings-Development.config file-->
  <appSettings file="Config/appSettings-Development.config"/>


  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.Data.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.XtraEditors.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="DevExpress.RichEdit.v12.2.Core, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B88D1754D700E49A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
        <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="UserControls" src="~/CustomControls/ctlHeader.ascx" tagName="Header"/>
        <add tagPrefix="UserControls" src="~/CustomControls/ctlSidebar.ascx" tagName="Sidebar"/>
        <add tagPrefix="UserControls" src="~/CustomControls/ctlMenu.ascx" tagName="Menu"/>
        <add tagPrefix="UserControls" src="~/CustomControls/ctlMenu2.ascx" tagName="Menu2"/>
        <add tagPrefix="UserControls" src="~/CustomControls/ctlBreadCrumb.ascx" tagName="BreadCrumb"/>
        <add tagPrefix="UserControls" src="~/CustomControls/ctlFooter.ascx" tagName="Footer"/>
        <add tagPrefix="UserControls" src="~/CustomControls/ctlCopyright.ascx" tagName="Copyright"/>
        <add tagPrefix="UserControls" src="~/CustomControls/ctlOnlineHelp.ascx" tagName="OnlineHelp"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Index2.aspx" name=".xxxxxxxxxxxxaddressing" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <trace enabled="false" requestLimit="40" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true"/>
       <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="480" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="480"/>
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
    <identity impersonate="true" password="" userName=""/>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" validate="false"/>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" validate="false"/>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--<httpModules>
            <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </httpModules>-->
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="15360" executionTimeout="360"/>


  </system.web>
  <!-- Designates locations on the site that are accessible without login -->
  <location path="ProviderLogin.htm">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="ErrorPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Index2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Logout.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Registration/CRegistration1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Registration/CRegistration2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Registration/CRegistration3.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Registration/CRegistration4.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Registration/CRegistrationC.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Help/ContactUs.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Help/NewsArchive.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Help/WebsiteSettings.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Help/TermsAndConditions.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Tools/PasswordReset.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Help/ProblemSubmission.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <!--<location path="Tracking/QuickTrack.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>-->
  <location path="Help/WebsiteAlerts.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Registration/Tree.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Registration/WebForm1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="NewTemplate.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <remove value="Default.htm"/>
        <add value="index2.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <!--<add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.1, Version=12.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>-->
      <!--<add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule"/>-->
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxHttpHandlerModule, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="DX.ashx" name="ASPxHttpHandlerModule" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add type="DevExpress.Web.ASPxUploadControl.ASPxUploadProgressHttpHandler, DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" verb="GET,POST" path="ASPxUploadProgressHandlerPage.ashx" name="ASPxUploadProgressHandler" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="NoControl"/>
    </staticContent>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <add fileExtension=".ttf" allowed="true"/>
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

  </system.webServer>


  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>

        <binding name="DEVServerBinding"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                 transactionFlow="false"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 messageEncoding="Text"
                 textEncoding="utf-8"
                 useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                 allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true"
                           inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                           enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"
                       proxyCredentialType="None"
                       realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"
                     negotiateServiceCredential="true"/>
          </security>
        </binding>

      </wsHttpBinding>

    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="xxxxxx"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="DEVServerBinding"
                contract="IUtility"
                name="IUtility">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="host/localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>

      <endpoint address="xxxxxx"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="DEVServerBinding"
                contract="IReferences"
                name="IReferences">
        <identity>
          <servicePrincipalName value="host/localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>



  <devExpress>
    <settings rightToLeft="false"/>
    <compression enableHtmlCompression="false" enableCallbackCompression="true" enableResourceCompression="true" enableResourceMerging="false"/>
    <themes enableThemesAssembly="true" styleSheetTheme="" theme="" customThemeAssemblies=""/>
    <errors callbackErrorRedirectUrl=""/>
  </devExpress>

  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
        <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669E0DDF0BB1AA2A" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.8.0" newVersion="2.0.8.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <file value="logs\"/>
      <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'_WebHost_Development_Log.txt'"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%level] %message Logger[%logger]%newline%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <levelvalue value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>

</configuration>
```

The AppPool on both servers is set up as "classic"

I have gone through IIS settings on both servers in a side-by-side comparison and I can't seem to find anything that is different.

The only design difference is that in the current production server, the website is a virtual application below the default website and the files are below wwwroot but in the Development server, I created a new website and the files are located in a websites folder on the C:\drive. The websites folder has a folder for the development website and in that is a folder that is the virtual application folder like what is used in the production server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to switch to integrated mode.

Comment: Well... that seemed to work but I do not understand why. The existing production site is running classic. I started the development server in integrated mode but because the legacy web.config had tags that were from pre .NET 4.0, I was getting errors in my local dev and so I switched ti to classic. The original project started with .NET 2.0 back in 2010.

Comment: can you post your web.config you use in classic mode?

Comment: The web.config I posted in my original post is the same one I am still using. The only change I made was in IIS, I changed the AppPool from Classic to Integrated. I didn't make any change in the web.config file. Please note that the only place I was getting the errors about classic/integrated mode was in my local dev computer trying to debug using IIS Express, not the Development Server with the full IIS install.

Comment: However, I would like to remove or change the web.config to remove the legacy code (.NET 2.0 - 3.5) an d just keep the .NET 4 changes. I have just not found a good example of what I need to change yet.

Comment: @Legends 2 -  If you put your post in the form of an answer rather than just a comment, I will mark it as answered so that you get the points